# Malloc, free and segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, free

I don't understand why, in this code, the call to "free" cause a segmentation fault:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *char_arr_allocator(int length);

int main(int argc, char* argv[0]){

    char* stringa =  NULL;
    stringa = char_arr_allocator(100);  
    printf("stringa address: %p\n", stringa); // same address as "arr"
    printf("stringa: %s\n",stringa);
    //free(stringa);

    return 0;
}

char *char_arr_allocator(int length) {
    char *arr;
    arr = malloc(length*sizeof(char));
    arr = "xxxxxxx";
    printf("arr address: %p\n", arr); // same address as "stringa"
    return arr;
}
```

Can someone explain it to me?

Thanks,
Segolas

Comment: Also have a look at http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/  it's really nice.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are allocating the memory using `malloc` correctly:

```
arr = malloc(length*sizeof(char));
```

then you do this:

```
arr = "xxxxxxx";
```

this will cause `arr` point to the address of the string literal `"xxxxxxx"`, ***leaking*** your `malloc`ed memory. And also calling `free` on address of string literal leads to undefined behavior.

If you want to *copy* the string into the allocated memory use `strcpy` as:

```
strcpy(arr,"xxxxxxx");
```

Comment: You are right on the UB part: Calling `free` with any pointer value (other than `NULL`) not from `malloc` or `realloc` gives undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The third line of `char_arr_allocator()` wipes out your `malloc()` result and replaces it with a chunk of static memory in the data page. Calling `free()` on this blows up.

Use `str[n]cpy()` to copy the string literal to the buffer instead.

Answer (score 2):

When you write a constant string in C, such as `"xxxxxx"`, what happens is that that string goes directly into the executable.  When you refer to it in your source, it gets replaced with a pointer to that memory.  So you can read the line

```
 arr = "xxxxxxx";
```

Treating `arr` as a number as something like:

```
 arr = 12345678;
```

Where that number is an address.  `malloc` has returned a different address, and you threw that away when you assigned a new address to arr.  You are getting a segfault because you are trying to free a constant string which is directly in your executable -- you never allocated it.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `arr` to the return value of `malloc()`, which is correct.  But you are then reassigning it to point at the string constant `"xxxxxxx"`.  So when you call `free()`, you're asking the runtime to free a string constant, which causes the seg fault.